# Why is my onclick function not working for the button inside a Mustache template?

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

I am trying to apply a event on a button but it doesn't seem to be responding to this code. I am using mustache templates for my data but I am not sure if thats the problem for it to not to resposd to getElementById tag or something. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script id="itemtpl" type="text/template">
    {{#items}}
            <div class ="item"> 
                <div class="item_image">
                    <img src = "{{item.image_url}}" />
                </div>
                <h3 class="item_name">{{item.menu_item_name}}</h3>
                <h4 class="item_price">${{item.menu_item_price}}</h4>
                <p class="item_description">    {{item.menu_item_description}}</p>
                <button type="button" class="addtocart" id="addtocart" >Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
    {{/items}}
    </script>

    <script>
        var addToCart = document.getElementById("addtocart");

        addToCart.onclick = function() {

        alert("Yayyy");

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you render the template before calling getElementById?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `onclick` property after the mustache template is rendered. `getElementById` will not find the element if it isn't yet in the DOM. Since the code that sets `onclick` is just in script tags without any sort of `document.ready`, it can execute before the page has finished rendering (and you have rendered the template). You don't want to set onclick until after you have rendered your mustache template. I suggest putting this code in a method and calling it after your render code.